# Get Values from dictionary present in List

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a list like,

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("MEASUREMENT");
list.Add("TEST");
```

I have a dictionary like,

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("BPGA", "TEST");
dict.Add("PPPP", "TEST");
dict.Add("RM_1000", "MEASUREMENT");
dict.Add("RM_2000", "MEASUREMENT");
dict.Add("CDMA", "TEST");
dict.Add("X100", "XXX");
```

Now, I want to get all matched data from dictionary based on list.
Means, all data from list match with dict value then get new dictionary with following mathched values

Is there any way to achieve this by using lambda expression?

I want result like this.

```
 Key     Value
"BPGA",    "TEST"
"PPPP",    "TEST"
"RM_1000", "MEASUREMENT"
"RM_2000", "MEASUREMENT"
"CDMA",    "TEST"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use the dictionary like a dictionary i.e. `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and have it as `dict.Add("TEST", new List<string>() { "BGPA", ... });`

Comment: It is not like that. I want to get new dictionary from existing one. but with lambda expression.

Comment: I know, I'm saying to change yopur structure to use the dictionary as it is meant to be used

Comment: Suppose, I use dict.Where(x => x.Value == "TEST" || x.Value == "MEASUREMENT") ; then I get proper result. but I don't know how much data present in list.

Comment: Well if you want to compare to the list something like `dict.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Value))` to get all of them more efficiently although see my answer it makes it a lot easier to work with and is how a dictionary is supposed to work, otherwise you might as well just have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the dictionary like it is intended to be used i.e. a common key with multiple values for example:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Then all you need to do when adding the values is:

```
dict.Add("TEST", new List<string>() { /*strings go in here*/ });
```

Then to get all the results from a key like:

```
List<string> testValues = dict["TEST"];
```

To make it safe however you should check that the key exists i.e.

```
if (dict.ContainsKey("TEST"))
{
    //Get the values
}
```

Then to add values to a current key you go do something like:

```
dict["TEST"].Add("NewValue");
```

If you insist on keeping the same structure, although I do not recommend it, something like the following will work:

```
List<string> testKeys = new List<string>();
foreach (var pairs in dict)
{
    if (pair.Value == "TEST")
    {
        testKeys.Add(pair.Key);
    }
}
```

Or even the following LINQ statement:

```
List<string> testKeys = dict.Where(p => p.Value == "TEST").Select(p => p.Key).ToList();
```

For a generic query to find the ones from your list use:

```
List<string> values = dict.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: **dict.Where(p => list.Contains(p.Value))**. This is the solution. Thanks you very much.